# Call method when app is opened

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'd like to call a method when my application shows, and not only on launch. For example, when my app starts and someone presses the home button, then clicks the app icon again, I want the method to be called.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various appdelegate methods available.

when you press HOME button, following methods are called

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
}
```

while when you again touch on icon, then these methods are called-

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}
```

So you can write your code in these methods.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into these when I get home.